# delete last node of doubly linked list (c++)

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have been working on a project for school involving doubly linked lists and i have been having trouble deleting the very last node of my list.

```
bool DLL::remove(string ss, int & count){

    Node* temp = new Node;                              

    if(headPtr == NULL){                                
        return false;                                   
    }
    else{                                               
        temp = headPtr;                                 
        for(int i = 0; i < itemCount-1; i++){           

            if(temp->ssn.compare(ss) == 0){             

                if(temp->pred == NULL){                 
                    count += 1;                         
                    itemCount -= 1;                     
                    headPtr = temp->succ;               
                    return true;
                }
                if(temp->succ != NULL){                 
                    temp->succ->pred = temp->pred;      
                    temp->pred->succ = temp->succ;      
                    return true;
        }
        if(temp->succ == NULL){     
            temp->pred->succ = NULL;
            return true;
        }

    }
    else{
        if(temp->succ == NULL){                 
            return false;                       
        }
        temp = temp->succ;  
    }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My code works when the item, or well, node now that i think about that, is at the beginning or anywhere in the middle but when it is the last item in the list it does not remove it.

Sample output:

list: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
when i remove 10, 30 and 50, the result is
list: 20, 40, 50

Any help would be appreciated.
Also succ stands for successor and pred stands for predecessor as per my professor.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: As for your problem, if you haven't done it before now is a great time to learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, to see what happens and monitor variables and their values and changes to their values.

Comment: Why are you allocating a new node in a function called remove?

Comment: Show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating up to `itemcount - 2` rather than `itemcount - 1` and so ignoring the last element because you're using `< itemcount - 1`. The loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
}
```

It's much easier to iterate over a linked list by following pointers though:

```
Node *node;
for (node = head; node != NULL; node = node->succ) {
}
```

Aside from your question, there is no need to allocate `temp` with `new` as it is given a value by being assigned to `head` etc. You should also call `delete` on the nodes you remove, as you will leak memory otherwise.

Comment: thanks a ton this helped alot, as for the delete i knew i was forgetting something as well